# how to understand this function with recursive call

Tags: python, recursion

```
def pretty(e, level=0):
    if len(e) > 0:
        e.text = '\n' + '\t' * (level + 1)
        for child in e:
            pretty(child, level + 1)
        child.tail = child.tail[:-1]
    e.tail = '\n' + '\t' * level
```

---

This Python function uses a recursive call in its 5th line. It has a for-loop in the function with a loop variable called `child`. But in its 6th line, it has a `child` variable too. Please help me understand where `child` was defined.

Comment: Is there any missing code?  The 'child' variable in the sixth line is out of scope.

Comment: ```child``` will be the very last child in ```e``` - the last child of the for loop. Try ```for thing in '1234': pass``` - when the loop finishes what is `thing`?

Comment: Thanks for @wwii , i think his answer is precise. It is a interesting feature in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the loop is finished, the last element of the iterable `e` has been assigned to `child`. Since the smallest enclosing scope is the body of the function ([`for` loops do not create their own scopes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules)), `child` is still in scope in the 6th line.

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'child' is a variable declared inline by the 'for'.

Have a look at this c# example:

```
     foreach (PuzzlePiece **piece** in myPuzzle.pieces)
     {
        piece.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine( piece.WhatNumberPieceAmI());
     }
```

The Foreach is creating a scoped variable that will exist within the Foreach scope { }.

You are looking at the equivalent thing in your Python code.

Good Luck!

Comment: Why would `C#` scoping rules apply to Python?

Comment: I know the variable 'child' in 5th line , it is a scoped variable in for-loop. but in 6th line , this 'child'  is out of the for-loop obviously, so i can't understand where it was defined

Comment: @Y.Eric-- No. The scope of `child` is definitively _not_ the body of the `for` loop. There is no such thing as `for`-loop-scope in Python. The scope of `child` is the body of the function `pretty`. A few of us keep trying to tell you this. The answers and comments that suggest that `child` in line 6 and `child` in line 5 are in different scopes are wrong. This is a common misunderstanding because there are many languages that _do_ scope the body of `for` loops. Just not Python.

Comment: Should I delete this answer?